VBA - Why does For Each iterator need to be Variant
Why does the VBA compiler require For Each iterators to be of type Variant?
For example, this code will throw error:
Public Sub IterationTest()

Dim arr(1 To 4) As String
Dim str As String

arr(1) = "A"
arr(2) = "B"
arr(3) = "C"
arr(4) = "D"

For Each str In arr
    Debug.Print str
Next

End Sub

whereas this one will not:
Public Sub IterationTest()

Dim arr(1 To 4) As String
Dim str As Variant

arr(1) = "A"
arr(2) = "B"
arr(3) = "C"
arr(4) = "D"

For Each str In arr
    Debug.Print str
Next

End Sub


It doesn't make much sense to force the use of Variant (or Object) type. Variant is meant to be (sparsely) used when the exact type of variable is not known at compile time, which is not the case in most uses of For Each. In most cases you're able to tell the type you'll be iterating over and could simply make your iterator this type.
Furthermore, it's not possible to have different kinds of data types in one collection. On each iteration of the loop you'll always be iterating over the same type. String won't suddenly become Boolean, which would justify the use of a flexible type like Variant. So why not allow the iterator to be strongly-typed?
It's an issue for me because Variant is the most memory-hungry type out there, and yet the compiler forces you to use it in every For Each loop, even when it could be easily omitted. Seems like a huge overlook from Microsoft.

it's not possible to have different kinds of data types in one collection - sure it is, try an array of Variant or Object. It's an issue for me because Variant is the most memory-hungry type out there - are you sure it's an actual issue for you that you have to use one variable of 16 bytes in size, or is it purely theoretical? Besides, this requirement is only for arrays. For collections, you can use an object-typed variable too.

That is with data fields and not for each dependent.
Dim g As Worksheet
For Each g In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Next g

I don't really know what answer you are looking for besides "because that's the way VB(A) works".

An answer explaining why does it work this way :)

1. PLEASE PLEASE do not use function names as variables. STR() is a function name. You will end up making your life very difficult.. 2. An answer explaining why does it work this way :) – KundaliniSin 50 mins ago The For Each loop iterates through elements in a collection or array. When you declare a loop variable for a For Each loop for a collection or array, it must be of type Variant because VBA does late binding when it comes to iterating through collections. This means that VBA determines the type of the items in the collection at runtime, rather than at compile time.

Iterators are objects.  They must be, they need to keep track where in the collection they are located.  A string or boolean can't do that.  A variant can.  A variable of an object type can, even if it is an object type that can't enumerate by itself.  Under the hood, an object can implement multiple interfaces.  Very little reasons to fret about the size of a variant, big objects only are worrisome when you create arrays or collections of them.  Can't do that with iterators.

Didn't you find some time to see and understand my answer? Iterated elements are not objects all the time. They only can be objects, too... They can be strings, integers etc. But Variant is the answer for all of them.

@HansPassant The variable that holds the current element from the collection being enumerated does not hold a reference back to the place in the collection, and is not by itself an iterator. An iterator is what manages that variable and assigns the next value to it. Even when the variable is a Variant, it is still not a VT_BYREF Variant, it is a dumb copy. So whatever reason there was to make the enumeration variable Variant, it cannot be that.

Firstly, what you say it is not generally true...
It is true only for collections and arrays. Why? Because collections and arrays can keep all kinds of elements (strings, numbers, objects etc.). A Variant declaration (because of that, it needs more memory than other types) have to substitute any of the possible elements type.
In the next code example you can see such iteration using the appropriate type declarations:
Sub IteratorDeclaration()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  For Each wb In Workbooks
    Debug.Print wb.name
  Next wb
  
  Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
  For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    Debug.Print ctrl.name
  Next ctrl
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     Debug.Print ws.name
  Next ws
  
  Dim txtB As TextBox 'for sheet Form text boxes...
  For Each txtB In ActiveSheet.TextBoxes
    Debug.Print txtB.name
  Next txtB
  'All the above used collections contain objects of a **known** type.  
  'That's why it is good to declare the iterator as the object type.
  'In this way, it is possible to return the object properties, not only the object itself...

  Dim myArr, myEl 'declared implicitele as Variant
  myArr = Split("a,b,c,d,e,f", ",")
  
  For Each myEl In myArr
    Debug.Print myEl
  Next myEl

  'and the most eloquent exammple:
  Dim myCol As New Collection, Iterator
  myCol.Add ActiveSheet
  myCol.Add 10
  myCol.Add "my text"
  For Each Iterator In myCol
    Debug.Print TypeName(Iterator)
  Next Iterator
  'How else could you declare the iterator to handle all such elements?
End Sub

You could also declare As Variant in all the other iterations involving known objects type! But this would be bed from memory handling point of view...
